MAX491 and MAX485 connection
Currently I'm trying to draw a PCB for MAX491 IC. The MAX491 will communicate with MAX485 IC. But I don't understand how to wire with each other. MAX491 has Y,Z,A,B pins otherwise MAX485 has only A,B pins.
Please help me with this?

How does it make sense for your application to wire a semi-duplex transceiver to a full duplex transceiver? We can't answer that question, we aren't the ones designing your system. You have to ask the person who is.

@Lundin there are lots of max491 ic on my stock right now so i basically decided to use them. Now things works. The max491 communicate with max485 using a simple jumper wires. I dont know why you mad at me and why you acting like that. "Justme" gave a perfect point for my situation and now its working. So there musnt be to hard to say something useful for newbies.

Then your actual question is how to replace a MAX485 with MAX491 in an existing semi-duplex design. That's an entirely different question. Also, exact part numbers matters a lot. There are flavours of these IC without ESD protection and flavours of them with ESD protection built-in. Which flavour you happen to have in stock matters a lot. You may need to add external TVS etc.

MAX485 has a transmitter and receiver on same two data pins so it is half duplex.
MAX491 has separate pins for transmit and receive so capable of full-duplex operation, but you simply connect them together for half-duplex operation so it has only two connections to bus like MAX485.

thanks man . with two jumper wires now it works. Goodday :)
for someone who is struggle with this can visit here; https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/FA312846/
